# how to submit form with html tags as value of input

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a form to search string between two word, sub-string, html tags.
This is my form.

```
<form action="" method="post">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>From: <input type="text" name="from" /></td>
        <td>To: <input type="text" name="to" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this is my php code.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

$frm1=$_REQUEST['from'];
$to1=$_REQUEST['to'];   
}
```

Form is submitting on same page.
When I enter any character or string into form, it works but when I enter any html tag like '< div id="block">'

into first input and "< div>" into second input, it doesn't work.

Value of 
    $frm1=$_REQUEST['from'];

is null.

Anyway, this would solve my problem.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes that is how it works. You have not entered any value in input["text"] thats why you are getting null. If you enter some value , you will get that string in backend.

Comment: What you are expecting there?

Comment: I entered in input "<div id="block">" . But because of this  "<>" it shows null.

Comment: @Jon — Only if you render the output as HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Comment: I want to post html tags name like <div id="block"> as input value.

Comment: @Quentin - thanks , as you suggested I got solution for this problem.